# Minecraft 1.14.4 Teleport in multiplayer mode a different player relitive to them selfs from (Datapack) function called from command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm cloning blocks in the x direction -1 at a time. I want to keep all players on these blocks with them so I teleport the player -1 relative to their current `Pos[0]` or X.

This works for me when the function is run from a repeating command block calling a datapack function as follows.

```
clone ~-9 ~-1 ~-2 ~63 ~5 ~2 ~-10 ~-1 ~-2 replace force

execute at @p run tp @p ~-1 ~ ~
```

As I'm executing the command `@p`

However this will not work for others. I do have a scoreboard to tell if a player is on the blocks so I can execute another function based on that scoreboard from this function. However I have tried multiple combos to get the other players in multiplayer mode to move -1 block in the x direction to no avail but I do move.

Comment: `at @p` → `as @a at @s`

Answer (score 2):

To clarify what @Fabian Röling meant, the reason your commands do not work is because you are using the @p selector instead of the @a selector. Your command, `execute at @p run to @p ~-1 ~ ~`, means run this command at the nearest player and teleport the nearest player to that position -1 blocks in the x direction.

What you really want is

```
execute as @a at @s run tp @s ~-1 ~ ~
```

which means run this command as all players, respecting each of their positions, and teleport each of them relative to their position -1 blocks in the x direction.

If this isn't what you want, I recommend clarifying your question.